# Programmatically Create Connect Button in Xcode5

Tags: ios, button, user-interface, xcode5

I am trying to programmatically add a connect button to my project in Xcode 5, similar to the one shown in concept to the example shown in this link:

[image]

The code I am using is shown below:

```
- (void) setupConnectButton
{
    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:self.peripheral.isConnected ? NSLocalizedString(@"Disconnect", nil) : NSLocalizedString(@"Connect", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(connectAction:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = (self.peripheral != nil);

    self.beatsPerMinute.hidden = !self.peripheral.isConnected;
    self.legendLabel.hidden = !self.peripheral.isConnected;

}
```

However, the button is not appearing when I launch the app...is it possibly because the graphs I created are somehow blocking the button in the view?

[image]

Edit: I am creating the graphs using the same code as in Apple's AcceleratorGraph project: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html

The code for drawing the graphs is shown below:

```
// The graph view itself exists only to draw the background and gridlines. All other content is drawn either into
// the GraphTextView or into a layer managed by a GraphViewSegment.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Fill in the background
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, graphBackgroundColor());
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

    CGFloat width = self.bounds.size.width;
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, 56.0);

    // Draw the grid lines
    DrawGridlines(context, 0.0, width);
}
```

Comment: are you using a navigation controller? could you show how you create your "graphs"?

Comment: Hi @sergio, I edited the question to show how the graphs are being drawn.
Thanks, 
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Try this lines of code

```
    UIBarButtonItem *firstButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(firstButtonAction:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *secondButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(secondButtonAction:)];

    UIToolbarTransparent *toolbar = [UIToolbarTransparent new];

    [toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 140,44)];
    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstButton, secondButton, nil]];

    UIBarButtonItem *customBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarButton;
```